# Передача метода в качестве параметра в java

Tags: java

Читал новые фичи в java 8, но так и не понял, можно ли в java передать метод в качестве параметра другому методу?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, речь всё-таки не о лямбда-выражениях, а о ссылках на методы (method references). Они ходят рядом с лямбда-выражениями, но всё же это отдельная штука.

Предположим, у вас есть метод, которому зачем-то посреди работы нужно преобразование строки в строку. Для этого можно воспользоваться готовым функциональным интерфейсом [`UnaryOperator<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html):

```
public void myMethod(UnaryOperator<String> stringTransformer) {
   // где-то в середине метода, возможно даже в цикле
   String transformedString = stringTransformer.apply(str);
   ...
}
```

Теперь в этот метод вы можете передать ссылки на подходящие методы. Тут подходят некоторые методы класса `String`, которые не принимают аргументов и возвращают новую строку. Например, можно вызвать так:

```
myMethod(String::trim);
```

Или так:

```
myMethod(String::toUpperCase);
```

Тогда, когда вы вызываете `stringTransformer.apply(str)`, это волшебным образом превратится в `str.trim()` или `str.toUpperCase()`.

Ещё тут вариант — передать ссылку на статический метод с одним параметром. Например, у вас в проекте есть такое:

```
public class StringUtils {
    public static String removeDots(String str) {
        return str.replace(".", "");
    }
}
```

Тогда вы можете и ссылкой на такой метод воспользоваться:

```
myMethod(StringUtils::removeDots);
```

И `stringTransformer.apply(str)` волшебным образом превратится в `StringUtils.removeDots(str)`. Ещё можно сделать instance-bound ссылку, привязанную к конкретному объекту. Например:

```
myMethod(Pattern.compile("foo").matcher("[foo]")::replaceFirst);
```

Тут уже `stringTransformer.apply(str)` волшебным образом возьмёт `str` в квадратные скобки (а точнее — заменит в `[foo]` подстроку `foo` на `str`).

Есть ещё ссылки на методы, создающие объект (типа `ArrayList::new`) или массив (типа `int[]::new`). В этом случае функциональный интерфейс должен соответствовать параметрам конструктора (в случае массива подразумевается один целый параметр — его длина). Ссылки на методы — мощная и красивая штука, но нередко всё-таки нужно полноценное лямбда-выражение. Например, последний пример яснее написать так:

```
myMethod(str -> "["+str+"]");
```

Answer (score 5):

Очень просто.

Лямбды в Java — не что иное, как интерфейсы с одним методом. Поэтому вы можете на выбор

- либо определить такой интерфейс сами,
- либо воспользоваться готовыми интерфейсами [отсюда](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) (возможно, вам придётся боксировать примитивные типы при этом).

Пример:

```
// определяем свой интерфейс
interface NameAndIndexPredicate {
    public boolean execute(String name, int index);
}

boolean apply(NameAndIndexPredicate p, String name, int index) {
    return p.execute(name, index);
}

apply((n, i) -> true, "VladD", 1);
```

```
import java.util.function.*;

// пользуемся готовым интерфейсом
boolean apply(BiPredicate<String, Integer> p, String name, int index) {
    return p.test(name, index);
}

apply((n, i) -> true, "VladD", 1);
```

---

Как правильно заметил @Tagir Valeev, метод можно передать в функцию точно так же, как и лямбду. Смотрите его ответ по поводу синтаксиса передачи методов.

Comment: Есть и для примитивных типов некоторые стандартные функциональные интерфейсы (`IntPredicate`, `ToIntFunction` и т. д.)

Comment: @TagirValeev: Угу, но не для всех вариантов. Например, для `(String, int) -> boolean` нету. Поэтому я и написал «_возможно_, вам придётся...».

Comment: Если аргументов больше двух или вы хотите checked-исключение кидать, то и для непримитивного типа придётся определять :-)

Comment: @TagirValeev: Угу. В .NET нет checked exception, но то же самое приходится делать для out- и ref-переметров. А ещё для такого типа интерфейса T, в котором возвращаемым типом является сам T :-D (в .NET это выглядит, например, так: `delegate T T(T t);`. Такое нужно, если вы захотите поиграться с Y-комбинатором.