# Передача функции как параметр другой функции

Tags: java, функции

Есть функция, которая делает замер времени выполнения и усредняет по минимумам результат.

```
public static long AverageTime(/*FUNCTION*/int cycles){

    long minValue = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    long sum =0;
    long time;

    for(int i = 0;i<cycles;i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<1000;j++){
            time = System.nanoTime();
            //FUNCTION
            time = System.nanoTime() - time;
            if(time<minValue){
                minValue = time;
            }
        }
        sum+=minValue;
    }
    return sum/cycles;
}
```

Можно ли как то вообще передать параметром функции функцию, чтобы она вызывалась и передавалась в месте `//FUNCTION` ?

Comment: Какие аргументы функция должна принимать и что возвращать?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev принимать int и возвращать массив интов. Еще интересует, можно ли как то обобщить, чтобы не зависеть от принимаемых и возвращаемых значений? Чтобы получить универсальную функцию  замера времени выполнения других функций

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/450285/201445

Comment: @Nazar019 обобщить не выйдет, так как компилятор должен точно знать типы в любой точке кода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static long AverageTime(IntFunction<Integer[]> function, int cycles) {
    ...
    Integer[] = function.apply(cycles);
    ...
}
```